# Is this flash effect possible with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash

I see a flash website with some eyecathing buttons with flash effect which I want to have with jQuery if possible here is the link of website -> http://www.goodthinking.com.ph/ .. any tips or sample if can this possible done using jquery code.. . thanks in advance.. .

Comment: You mean the effect where each button takes 30 seconds to load, one at a time, and the actual page text doesn't appear until all buttons have loaded?

Comment: exactly and also the rolling of puzzle pieces when mouse hover.. .thanks for response I appreciated.. .

Comment: All I say was gray. Page didn't load past that.... yup, you can do that in jQuery too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you could build something close, but with less browser support. The puzzle pieces could be stored as background images on `<div/>` elements, then the divs could be positioned to "fit" as puzzle pieces, yet still be move-able by animating their position properties with a custom jQuery `$.animate({})`. The noise could be played on `:hover` with an `<audio/>` element in browsers that support it, and the flip effect could be achieved using a [3D transform](http://webkit.org/blog/386/3d-transforms/), typically done by adding and removing CSS classes that define webkit animation keyframes.

You should seriously consider, however whether a whizz-bang effect actually helps people find the content on the website, or gets in the way. If you do want the effect and can design it in such a way that it degrades in browsers that don't support the effect, or all of the effects, then you have a cross-browser solution that is not the same everywhere, but doesn't penalize all users either by requiring they have a browser plugin.

Comment: Hi Andy,
Thanks for best response and a great tips.. .I'm also aware in browser compatibility which all of the effect will be not working the same with other browser thats why also I don't want to have a flash content it just because it always require plugins and to much time take to load..I better consider this tips Andy thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible? Probably yes.

Would I recommend doing it with jQuery or javascript? No.